# R %change from last value on RHS y axis to correspond in position with LHS y axis scale values

Tags: r

I have a plot and can get a LHS y axis and RHS yaxis

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- cumsum(x) 

lastval <- tail(y,1)
pchange <- (y-lastval)*100/lastval
plot(1:100,y)

axis(side = 4)
```

However I am trying to show the %change from the last value on the RHS y axis but I am uncertain how to do this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in the following set of steps:

```
par(mar = c(5, 5, 3, 5)) # right side margin must be adjusted for mtext
plot(1:100, y)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(1:100, pchange, axes = FALSE, ylab="", xlab="") #axes, ylab and xlab prevents overwritting
axis(side = 4) # adds the right scale
mtext("Change in [%]", side=4, line=3)
```

**EDIT:**
Values of RHS and LHS are linked:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- cumsum(x) 

lastval <- tail(y,1)
labels <- round(100*(seq(-2,10,2)-lastval)/lastval, 1)

plot(1:100,y, main=(paste("Last Value is ", round(lastval,2))) )
axis(side = 4, at=seq(-2,10,2), labels=labels)
abline(h=seq(-2,10,2), col="grey")
mtext("Change in [%]", side=4, line=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What I really wanted was the RHS scale values to be aligned and corresponding to the LHS scale values so you could draw  horizontal lines between the LHS and RHS scales.

Comment: Yes. I need a base solution and not ggplot.

Comment: The RHS is just a transformation of LHS. No need to compute pchange. I have set the LHS breaks manually.